# (Selenium WebDriver+ Python3) How to verify the link leads to an image or at leat return it's file extension?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to determine wether link contains an image or not. The problem is, link is in this kind of format:

```
src="https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2474062/b99de56b-611f-4e74-8d4a-69ea382bd137/s1200"
```

The src link does not contain the file extension itself. I was unable to find a proper solution anywhere.

I have tried using `imghdr` to determine the extension but it only works on locally stored files.

Could there be a way to store the file in a buffer which I can feed to `imghdr` ?

I'm fairly new to Selenium, any kind of advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the following information you can find in the title tag, in case of your link:

s1200 (JPEG Image, 1200 × 907 pixels) - Scaled (73%)

hope it help you.

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://avatars.mds.yandex.net/get-pdb/2474062/b99de56b-611f-4e74-8d4a-69ea382bd137/s1200")

title = driver.title
print(title)
# s1200 (JPEG Image, 1200 × 907 pixels) - Scaled (73%)

driver.close()
```